# Memory allocated for structures

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment

I have the structure

```
typedef struct EData
{
    int a;
    char c;
}
Edata obj;
```

`a` is the integer variable so it takes 4 bytes and the `c` is the char variable so it takes 
1 byte, totalling 5 bytes

But when I print `sizeof(obj)` it shows **8 bytes**.

What is the reason?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [How do I find the size of a struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143025/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-a-struct)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because on 32bit systems memory is aligned at `4byte (32bit)` boundaries so it has to multiple of 4bytes, see [`Data structure alignment`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Comment: Not quite... not *all* memory is aligned at 4-byte boundaries. For example, a struct that only contained `char` elements could easily have a size that is not a multiple of four.

Comment: Wouldn't that produce a non-aligned memory access while accessing such  an element?

Comment: Also you could use `#pragma pack(1)` on Visual Studio to set alignment to 1 byte. Then you should get 5 bytes as `sizeof(Edata)`.

Comment: No - whether a memory access is aligned or not depends both on the address, and on the size of the object being accessed. A single-byte element is correctly-aligned whatever alignment it is stored at, so a structure consisting entirely of single-byte elements is also correctly-aligned at any address.

Answer (score 3):

`int` is 4 bytes, `char` is 1 byte. However, your compiler [aligns each `struct` to a word](http://www.moythreads.com/wordpress/2007/08/05/memory-alignment/) (a word is 4 bytes on 32 bit architecture) as it improves performance. Therefore each instance of `EData` will be rounded up to 2 words (or 8 bytes).

What you end up with is something like this:

```
typedef struct EData {
    int a;
    char c;
    char padding[3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The increase in size you notice is due to compiler's padding.
Compiler adds extra bytes to enforce correct byte boundaries.
So compiler adds the extra bytes to enforce the proper location for each member according to its type.
There is an option to stop compiler to do this (packed directive) but it is best to avoid it (except in corner-cases)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a problem for you, you can either use `#pragma` or a compiler switch (a variety of compilers has such a switch).